# When was the word "baccalauréat" first used in France?

Tags: étymologie, histoire, éducation

I have just read the etymology of the word; quite fascinating indeed. But I would also want to know when this word was introduced into the language. My guess is somewhere in the Middle Ages, but I would really like to know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the etymology you've read is “from *bacca* (berry) and *laureatus* (covered in laurel)”, that was probably invented after the fact. *Laureatus* might have influenced the ending of the word but *bacca* was probably made up to explain what remained at the beginning. The [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baccalaur%C3%A9at) has a more researched (though not absolutely certain) history.

The term probably evolved from the Medieval Latin *baccalarius*, also attested as *baccalaureus*. The [origin of this term is contested](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor#Origin_and_medieval_usage). One hypothesis is that it is derived from *bacca* from the Latin *[vacca](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vacca#Latin)* (cow), hence *baccalarus* farm-hand, then lower-status person who might be an apprentice to a knight, hence knight in training. Another hypothesis is that a *baccalarus* is a person wielding a *[baculum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baculum#Latin)* (stick), again a knight in training.

Around the 16th century, it seems that the word evolved to *bacchilaureatus* or *baccalaureatus*, under the influence of *laureatus*, after it had been used in universities. It came to mean a junior student and a junior diploma. Note that universities at this time still used Latin, not French. *Baccalauréat* is the French form that appeared in the late 17th century.

A similar word *bacchalariatus* or *bachalariatus*, meaning a junior member of a liturgical choir, probably influenced the university term as well. I don't know the origin of this word (it may or may not be related to the knight-in-training meaning). A *bachalariatus* diploma is [attested](http://books.google.fr/books?id=hx8vAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA415&lpg=PA415&dq=%22bachalariatus%22&source=bl&ots=MZZSkUgrmU&sig=y3y-4uwbrG7kYja82TA8OEOx2CM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rK_iUZCUMYbMhAeruICoCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bachalariatus%22&f=false) in the 16th century.

The etymology of this and related words is discussed at length (in Latin) by [Du Cange](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/BACCALARII3), but beware that his conclusions have been contested.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the etymology I've read. What you've written here is absolutely amazing stuff. As I'm an etymology fan myself, I think I'll be posting more similar questions in the future hoping you'll always answer them. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2):

**In the middle age**, *XIII century* at the University of Paris.

The word come from the latin word "bachalariatus" which was the first rank in the process for becoming a knight.

The first "bac" was in 1808.

[Baccalauréat en France](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccalaur%C3%A9at_en_France#Du_Moyen_.C3.82ge_.C3.A0_la_R.C3.A9volution_fran.C3.A7aise).